# How to send data through central mode to peripheral?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an application where Client App starts BLE scanning in "Central" mode and there is a scanner App which Acts as "Peripheral",client will keep scanning for Scanners (Beacons) with specific id (where the Scanners are advertising the same id) when that both id match data is sent over BLE to the scanner app I have an [example code](https://github.com/0x7fs/Core-Bluetooth-Transfer-Demo) which works perfectly from peripheral to central but i don't have idea about my case how it work.

Answer (score 1):

The Demo which you are following is the correct one for a beginner. In this Demo, app is sending text data from TextView. The text data is passed in octet form, in iOS it is considered as Data (.utf8).

Now, question is, which type of data you want to send from Central to Peripheral.

The General flow is:
 1. Central will proximate peripheral so that other Bluetooth manager can scan it. 
 2. Once anyone try to connect with that peripheral, then on successful connection, it will return available Services and Characteristics inside of those each services.
 3. Based on characteristic, you can write your own logic to send text, images, audio, video or anyother data from Central to Peripheral.

Just follow the Demo link which you are following. Thanks.

Comment: i don't know how Central will proximate peripheral do you know any delegate method?

Comment: i follow all the step but i don't know why data not transfer .  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) this function not call